# Is this may-flowering grass an Echinochloa (barnyard grass)?

Tags: species-identification, botany

There's a grass growing in my thyme pot on my balcony, that's currently flowering (end of May, Paris region, France, southern exposure, windy conditions), and I'm wondering what species it is:

[image: grass in my thyme pot]

Here are a picture where details of the flower and leaves may be more visible:

[image: details of the flower]

I tried to search using my old determination key for French flora (G. Bonnier / G. De Layens), and after much hesitations, I guess it could be what is called "Oplismenus Grus-galli" in this book.
Internet tells me it is now called [Echinochloa crus-galli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echinochloa_crus-galli). The base of the plant indeed has a similar way of growing, and the flowers are a bit similar.

Does this look plausible? Do you see a better match?

Can I use the seeds when they are ripe (for instance to put in home-made bread)?